# Storing Accelerometer values in a variable

Tags: android, variables, accelerometer, android-sensors

I'm wondering about a way to store accelerometer values into a variable, specifically the X value. I need to store the value into a variable to i can use it in another class without having to rely on the onSensorChanged to get a current read on the data. My eventual goal is to be able to control a bitmap's coordinates based on the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the values without `onSensorChanged()`. However, you can pass them to your other class very easily.

Declare a global (or local and final) instance of your class in the class that has `onSensorChanged()`. Something like:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Then, create a method in MyClass that takes the x value as a parameter and updates everthing else

```
public class MyClass {
    public void updateX(float x) {
        //Call all the other methods here with the new X value
    }
}
```

Then, in `onSensorChanged()` simply use:

```
obj.updateX(theXValue);
```

Comment: I have actually tried that already. The problem is that I need to make a method in a class that accepts the accelerometer value from another class, and then i need to make a call in ANOTHER class that uses the accelerometer data in the SECOND class to change the bitmaps coordinates in the THIRD class. So I need to store the accelerometer data in another class as if that class has direct scope access to it. This way didn't really work for me as I always came up with 0.0